# Deploying to Vervel - Qwik City + Express Adapter

Tags: node.js, express, deployment, vercel, qwik

My project makes use of Prisma, and it will take a lot to convince me to move to Prisma cloud, so I am trying to deploy to Vercel with the Qwik Express Adapter. However, after deploying (I will put my config below), I get the Vercel 404 page when I visit the website. Has anyone else gone down the route and if so can you help? Thanks!

**Build Settings**

Framework Preset: Vite

Build command: `npx prisma generate && vite build`

Output Directory: `dist`

Install Command: `npm install`

Development Command: `vite`

Comment: Have you in the project the folder .vercel/output/functions?
Are you used "npm run qwik add vercel-edge" command to configure qwik for vercel?